# Robot framework Keyword is not identified when java.lang and java.util are imported in python file

Tags: javascript, java, python, robotframework

I'm a new for Robot Framework and python, working on using Robot Framework with jython for TI code composer Debug server scripting operations.
using : `jython2.7.2,robot framework- Pycharm 2020.3,python 3.7`.
path Environmental variables are added as below :

```
C:\ti\ccs930\ccs\ccs_base\DebugServer\packages\ti\dss\java\dss.jar
C:\ti\ccs930\ccs\ccs_base\DebugServer\packages\ti\dss\java\com.ti.ccstudio.scripting.environment_3.1.0.jar  C:\ti\ccs930\ccs\ccs_base\DebugServer\packages\ti\dss\java\com.ti.debug.engine_1.0.0.jar
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-15.0.1\bin
C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32
C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\Scripts
```

---

Code snippet are as below :
enter code here

Emulator.py :

```
    #*****************************************************
        from java.lang import *
        from java.util import *
        from com.ti.debug.engine.scripting import *
        from com.ti.ccstudio.scripting.environment import *
        from decimal import *
    #*****************************************************
    def CreateEnvironment():
        # Create our scripting environment object - which is the main entry point into  any script and
        # the factory for creating other Scriptable Servers and Sessions
        script = ScriptingEnvironment.instance()

        # Create a log file in the current directory to log script execution
        script.traceBegin("BreakpointsTestLog_python.xml", "DefaultStylesheet.xsl")

        # Set our TimeOut
        script.setScriptTimeout(100000)

        # Log everything
        script.traceSetConsoleLevel(TraceLevel.ALL)
        script.traceSetFileLevel(TraceLevel.ALL)

        # Start up CCS
        ccsServer = script.getServer("CCSServer.1")
        ccsSession = ccsServer.openSession(".*")
        print("Creating Environment...");
        # Get the Debug Server and start a Debug Session
        debugServer = script.getServer("DebugServer.1")
        return debugServer,script,ccsServer,ccsSession
    #****************************************************
```

EmulatorTest.robot :

```
*** Settings ***
Library  Emulator.py


*** Variables ***

*** Test Cases ***
Emulator Test functionality
    [Documentation]     TEST DESCRIPTION:
    ...
    ...     Verify that the Test script can launch target configuration and
    ...     connect to target, create a debug server and hit and verify breakpoint .

    [Tags]  TC-EmulatorTest-001

    CreateCCSEnvironment

*** Keywords ***
CreateCCSEnvironment
    CreateEnvironment
```

---

I am able to execute the python file successfully for creating code composer environment for DSS but the same was not able to do using robot.

Comment: Why do you think it's not working? If you're getting an error, please post the actual error.

Comment: Hi ..thanks for the replay...when i executed the robot file Keyword in python file is not getting identified the error displayed as below :No keyword with name 'CreateEnvironment' found. Did you mean:
    Create CCS Environment

Comment: if i remove the below statements from the python script file the keyword is getting identified but i need the below statements in my script as i need to use Java stuffs:                                    
        from java.lang import *
        from java.util import *
        from com.ti.debug.engine.scripting import *
        from com.ti.ccstudio.scripting.environment import *
        from decimal import *

Comment: This can't possibly be your code. The first block of python has indentation errors which prevent it from running. Are you sure you're not getting import errors in addition to the error you're reporting?

Comment: i am able to execute the python file successfully without any issues, even robot files keywords are getting identified if i remove Java stuffs:ava stuffs: from java.lang import * from java.util import * from com.ti.debug.engine.scripting import * from com.ti.ccstudio.scripting.environment import * from decimal import *